# ADF Import Data From Excel Into ADF Table

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I wish to import a series of data from excel to my table through adf. I follow the way of this blog(http://technology.amis.nl/2010/09/16/adf-11g-import-from-excel-into-an-adf-table) yet still fail to do so. Any suggestion? I can't even simple call valueChangeEvent from from value change listener on my page. Below is my code

```
  ADF Page:
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2">
          <af:inputFile label="File:" id="if1"
                        valueChangeListener="#{uploadTelephoneUsageBean.fileUploaded}"
                        autoSubmit="true"/>
          <af:commandButton text="Upload" id="cb1"
                            actionListener="#{uploadTelephoneUsageBean.check_file_upload}"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
 Request Scope Manage Bean:
     public void fileUploaded(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    // Add event code here...        
    UIComponent Temp_uic=valueChangeEvent.getComponent();
    Temp_uic.processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();

    System.out.println("Check value change ");
    try {
        UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue(); 
        parseFile(file.getInputStream());
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(valueChangeEvent.getComponent());
        eventADF=valueChangeEvent;
    } catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

No syntax error message showing. I can't view "Check value change". Any idea regarding this issues?

Comment: Have you added 'usesUpload="true"' in your <af:form> ?

Comment: That 1 need to implemented "Form" right? I already try this method. Apart from that is that other thing i miss up?

Comment: Please tell us your exact Jdev version! There are other samples for losing files available. Have you tried other samples which come complete with the sources?

Comment: @TimoHahn i already find out the answer. For run this fuction in page fragment all you need to do was wrap the it by a pane tab. Then you could run it as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ADF Version 11g 11.1.1.7.0 in order to import data from excel in page fragment. You need to put a panel tab on top of it. Else it will show error message. My code as below:

```
  **<af:panelTabbed id="pt1">**
    <af:showDetailItem text="File Upload" id="sdi1"
                       styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.inputValue}"
                    label="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.hints.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.hints.mandatory}"
                    columns="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.hints.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.hints.precision}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.hints.tooltip}"
                    id="it31">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.InvoiceNumber.validator}"/>
      </af:inputText>
      <af:spacer width="20" height="20" id="s2"/>
      <af:inputFile id="if1" autoHeightRows="0" label="File:"
                    value="#{UploadTelephoneUsageBean.uploadFile}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{UploadTelephoneUsageBean.fileUploaded}"/>
      <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1"/>
      <af:commandButton text="Upload" id="cb1" partialSubmit="true"
                        actionListener="#{UploadTelephoneUsageBean.check_file_upload}"/>
    </af:showDetailItem>
  **</af:panelTabbed>**
```